# Source for diaspora Jews not being able to return to the Land of Israel during the days of the Messiah

Tags: messiah, aliya-laaretz

Recently someone told me about a *chazal* that states that during the days of *Mashiach*, Jews who had not already relocated to the Land of Israel would no longer be able to do so.

I am familiar with this concept [when it comes to converts](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86017/487). Is anyone familiar with the source for this idea when it comes to making *aliyah*?

Comment: I don't even know where to begin with looking for an answer to this. I assume from the fact that the question is even asked in this manner that you're referring to those who are alive when Mashiach comes, not to those who have passed and will be revived. Therefore, this question is only valid according to the Ramban's and Rambam's (distinct from each other) views regarding Mashiach, as opposed to the Ramchal's that all of this occurs *after* the world explodes. (con't)

Comment: From the fact that this is only valid according to a subset of Rishonim leads me to believe that such a statement cannot be in a Chazal, but could be traced to a Rishon who holds of one of the former views.

Comment: When provided with an unusual quote, it's helpful to ask the person for the source. Often, the alleged “source”, when seen in context, doesn’t quite say what the person purported it to have said. You can politely say that you’re unfamiliar with the quote, and if they care to locate it for you, you would be happy to discuss it then. If they insist that it says does so, and how dare you suggest that it doesn’t, how can you insinuate that I’m lying etc., don’t lose your cool. Just calmly respond that sometimes people make mistakes and misquote something that they may have read many years prior.

Comment: Also, I see a *ton* of sources discussing Techi'as Hameisim, where those who are buried outside Eretz Yisrael are revived later, but I can't find a source discussing those who are alive.

Comment: @IsraelReader Before or after Mashiach? According to the Ramchal, I'd interpret those lines to mean that after Gog and Magog, after the world has its rest and renewal, *then* will we be gathered in to Eretz Yisrael. It's not so simple what the order of Techias Hameisim, Mashiach, and Olam Haba are, or if some of those are the same, or if the Gemaras about everyone dying and the world remaining dormant for 1-2 millennia is meant literally or not.

Comment: @DonielF We pray 3 times daily: וקבצנו יחד מארבע כנפות הארץ . We also say in the morning: והביאנו לשלום מארבע כנפות הארץ.

Comment: @DonielF I'm not familiar with the Ramchal that you're referring to. Can you please provide the source?

Comment: @DonielF Which Rambam are you referring to? The Rambam that I'm familiar with (Yad, Hilchos Melachim 11:4) states that one of the hallmarks identifying the King Messiah is the fact that he gathered in the dispersed of Israel, which I presume to mean the Jews of the Diaspora.

Comment: This is something I hear a lot, especially from people already there trying to convince others to make Aliya. I haven't heard it in the name of Chazal though. It's unsourced when mentioned.

Comment: @Israel I meant his view on the order of Yemos Mashiach, described in Teshuvah ch. 8-9, is theoretically compatible with the view presented in OP. You’re correct that Rambam himself can not hold of this view, but a theoretical later Rishon who agrees with Rambam’s order of the end of days could still disagree with the Rambam in Hilchos Melachim.

Answer (score 1):

the prophesy about moshiach in isaiah chapter 11 ends with a very detailed description about the gathering of the exiles see there. prophesies about קיבוץ גליות the gathering of the exiles, are found in as early as פרשת ניצבים where it says ״וקבצך מכל העמים אשר הפיצך ה׳ אלקיך שמה״

Comment: To play devil's advocate: maybe that's before moshiach comes?

Comment: in the nevuah in yeshaya chapter 11 after going on a long description about moshiach it says "and it will be on that day..." and then goes on along description for the whole rest of the chapter and the entire chapter after it about kibbutz galuyot the gathering of the exiles see there