# When moshiach comes, will it be impossible for Jews to make aliyah?

Tags: messiah, aliya-laaretz

Since with this worldwide pandemic, you can find tons of information about what will happen, or what could happen when moshiach comes. Some rabbis state that once he shows up, it will be too late for us to make aliyah. Well, isn't the duty of moshiach to bring back the exiles? At this point I am very confused.

Comment: Duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/112100/1739

Comment: "Some rabbis state that once he shows up, it will be too late for us to make aliyah." Who, where?